# Save a Image using ContentService in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6, umbraco7

I want to add a image using contentservice in umbraco , can it bo done simply using setValue method, what do I need to pass to the setValue Method?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [MediaService](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/MediaService) instead of the contentservice.

```
// check ApplicationContext.Current != null
var ms = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService;
var newMediaItem = ms.CreateMedia(file.FileName, <parentId>, Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image);
newMediaItem.SetValue(Constants.Conventions.Media.File, file);
ms.Save(newMediaItem);
```

Comment: `ms.Save(mimage);` ? I think "mimage" here should be "newMediaItem".